# My Delete Button button not working invalid cursor state - no current row

Tags: derby, netbeans-8

Delete button not working it says invalid cursor state - no current row, there are no errors in the source code is the code lacking on why is it not working?

```
private void DeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
       try {
        int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you 
   sure you want to delete the records?","Delete Button Message 
   Box",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StockPage.this, "Record Deleted");
        rs.deleteRow();
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM STOCKNEW";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                   rs.next();
    int id_col = rs.getInt("ITEM");
    String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
    String description = rs.getString("DESCRIPTION");
    String amt = rs.getString("AMOUNT");

    update_table();
    TextItem.setText(id);
    TextDescription.setText(description);
    TextAmount.setText(amt);

    
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StockPage.this, "Records was not Deleted");
        }

        }
    catch(SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StockPage.this, err.getMessage());
    }
}                                      


}
```

Comment: Try and focus on one broke thing at a time...

Comment: okay wait I'll edit it